# Ubuntu 21.04. How to update Timeshift?

Tags: apt, package-management, updates, timeshift

I’ve got Timeshift 20.11.1 installed. The latest version of Timeshift is 21.09.1. How do I update Timeshift to the latest version? Seems my Timeshift is not updated as part of Ubuntu Software Center updates.

I went to the Timeshift github https://github.com/teejee2008/timeshift but don’t see any deb files for 21.09.1; I only see source code files. How to update my Timeshift to 21.09.1? Thanks.

[image]

Comment: `Seems my Timeshift is not updated as part of Ubuntu Software Center updates.` -- See https://askubuntu.com/q/151283/124466

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why don't the Ubuntu repositories have the latest versions of software?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/151283/why-dont-the-ubuntu-repositories-have-the-latest-versions-of-software)

Comment: Timeshift 20.11 is the version packaged for Ubuntu 21.04 and Ubuntu 21.10. Timeshift 21.09 is the version packaged for Ubuntu 22.04, currently in testing, to be released in April 2022. You are welcome to help test it.

Comment: @user535733 Good info. Thanks. Helpful.

Comment: @user535733 It does not answer the question "**How to** use the latest timeshift in an older version of Ubuntu"

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi true; it was not an attempt to answer. Your answer is very good; no other seems needed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Timeshift PPA (maintained by the developer)](https://launchpad.net/%7Eteejee2008/+archive/ubuntu/timeshift) hosts the latest version of Timeshift. Open a terminal and enter the following commands one by one.

```
sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:teejee2008/timeshift
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install timeshift
```

Comment: This worked. I updated Timeshift to latest version. Thanks.